# What are leading zeroes in regards to HyperLogLog?

Tags: redis, hyperloglog, nosql

I was reading antirez.com and Wikipedia and some other sources to understang what HLL is and how it works, but each time the term "**Leading Zeroes**" is used I stumble. Please explain what it means when we talk about HyperLogLog.

Comment: What if it just means the same as everywhere else, i.e. zero digits at the beginning of a (often fixed length) number?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen a number only have leading zeroes if it was represented as string. Then I ask, what is this number and how and why it was converted to a string with so many leading zeroes.

Comment: Do you consider fixed length numbers strings? A 32-bit integer for instance can have leading zeros and I wouldn't consider it a string.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen "The other part of the hash is used to count the longest run of leading zeroes in the hash" whatever it means

Comment: Hashes are usually fixed length numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Leading zeroes is the number of 0s before the first 1 in the binary representation of the hash. It is equivalent to computing the [most significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit).

HyperLogLog algorithm does not really depend on computing these leading zeroes, it just needs to check a known prefix in the binary representation of the hash. It happens that computing the most significant bit is fast on most hardware implementations.